# Autobahn TestSuite: Missing wampclient mode

Tags: php, python, autobahn

I'm trying to test a PHP implementation of a [WAMP2](http://wamp.ws/spec/) server with [Autobahn|Testsuite](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/).  According to the [documentation](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/usage.html#mode-wampserver-wampclient), there should be a mode called "wampclient" available.  However, when I run `wstest -m wampclient -w <server info>` I get an error that says that the wampclient mode is invalid.

What do I need to do to get the wampclient mode to work?  Is there another way to run tests against a WAMP2 server?

I'm using the following versions of software on OSX 10.9.3:

- Python 2.7.5
- Autobahn 0.8.9
- AutobahnTestSuite 0.6.1
- Twisted version: 14.0.0

Comment: The feature (`wampclient`) got lost some time ago during refactoring. It's not yet there again. What kind of WAMPv2? A component host for running WAMP PHP components, connected to external WAMP router, or a WAMP router in PHP? There are others currently also interested in WAMP/PHP - can you come to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/autobahnws or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wampws?

Comment: @oberstet we're working on a php implementation of WAMPv2. https://github.com/voryx/AutobahnPHP
Are you planning to add the wampclient mode back into the testsuite?